# I need to capture the amount of time a user spends on a page in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I need to capture the total elapsed time that a user spends on a page in ASP classic (.asp). This has NOTHING to do with profiling the page to get timing of how long the page logic takes to execute. I am only interested in capturing the amount of time each user spends on the site and specifically on a certain page. The elapsed time would also need to be captured if there was a unexpected disconnect on the client side.

Comment: Your best bet is integrating an analytics package like [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/). You will struggle to do this server-side especially detecting client disconnects.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I might use client-side JavaScript to capture (poll) a server-side REST API during `window.onload` and `window.onunload`, along with polling timers setup for a specific timing resolution (eg, every minute).  If your server-side REST API doesn't receive a response within that timer resolution, then it might be safe to say the client was either disconnected or navigated away from your site.  Otherwise, you might be able to use IIS logs to get some rough estimates between .asp log entries.

Comment: Thanks! I need the page to log the elapsed time in the database at the point of disconnect - so that is why looking through IIS logs or using something like google analytics doesn't really apply here.  I will look into window.onload and window.onunload.  That might do the trick. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Google Analytics is totally useless for what you want and will only slow down the download of your pages. When sites used Access databases and global.asa it was possible to get a list of currently active users. But Access is a problem today. However it is programmable.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if a client is disconnected or not there is an ASP method

```
response.IsClientConnected
```

Your code would have to call the method from time to time to make sure they were connected.... it is ususally used before starting on a large process to make sure the user is still there.

I've never used it and not sure how accurate it might be. Javascript is still your best bet here to capture onclose of the browser but if a user disconnects by power failure or network conditions I don't think any tool is 100% going to be able to help you.